# Set max Date in datapicker field JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to set maximum date in datapicker field. I use jQuery UI

```js
function zerofill(i) {
    return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i;
}

$( function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var today = now.getFullYear() + '-' + zerofill(now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();
    $( "input[id^='datepicker']" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        maxDate: "0",
        minDate: "-60",
        monthNames: [ "Styczeń", "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwiecień", "Maj", "Czerwiec", "Lipiec", "Sierpień", "Wrzesień", "Pańdziernik", "Listopad", "Grudzień" ]
    }).val(today);
});
```

Here I have `maxDate: "0"` field which work just fine:

[image: date picker]

but still it is possible to change date by hand in field.

I used

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker[2]" min="<%=LocalDate.now().minusMonths(2)%>"
  max="<%=LocalDate.now()%>" name="calculationDate">
```

but it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Hi plucins, could you please show the output of  min="<%=LocalDate.now().minusMonths(2)%>"
           max="<%=LocalDate.now()%>", maybe they are not in the correct format which datepicker required.

Comment: Formats match 
https://imgur.com/V5Dyyr2

First line is field pointed above
Second line <p><%=LocalDate.now()%></p>

Comment: I think you need to add attribute `onchange='validatePassedDate(..)'` with corresponding logic. UPDATE: in html5 you could use type='date' - maybe it could help you

Comment: @ZhenyaM thats works only on Chrome and present extra native calendar.